# How to collect restaurant ratings from TripAdvisor with date of rating?

Tags: node.js, protractor, tripadvisor

I would like to see how the ratings of a restaurant changed over time, so I thought to collect the ratings on TripAdvisor together with the date they were issued by users. I thought of using protractor for that because it lets me programmatically interact with the browser. What other good (perhaps Node.js based) options would be suitable for this kind of task?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Request.js (https://www.npmjs.com/package/request) library to pull html data for the restaurant, then use Cheerio.js (https://www.npmjs.com/package/cheerio) to parse the resulting HTML.

Here's an example of parsing out the reviews.

NB: Remember when scraping that you may be breaching the website terms and conditions. Do not repeatedly scrape the page every 100 ms for example, you will be blocked!

```
"use strict";

const request = require('request');
const fs = require('fs');
const cheerio = require('cheerio');
const _ = require('lodash');

/* Change to whichever! */
const restaurantUrl = "https://www.tripadvisor.ie/Restaurant_Review-g60745-d1954989-Reviews-Italian_Express_Pizzeria-Boston_Massachusetts.html";

function getReviewDate(reviewRoot) {
    return _.get(reviewRoot, 'children[1].attribs.title', null);
}

function getReviewTitle(reviewRoot) {

    return _.get(reviewRoot.parent, 'children[1].children[0].children[0].children[0].data', null);
}

function getReviewDetails(htmlData) {

   const $ = cheerio.load(htmlData);

   var result = $('div.rating.reviewItemInline');

   let reviews = [];

   for(let resultIndex = 0; resultIndex < result.length; resultIndex++)
   {
       var review = { date: getReviewDate(result[resultIndex]), title: getReviewTitle(result[resultIndex])};
       reviews.push(review);
   }

   return reviews;
}

function getReviewSummaries(htmlData) {

    const $ = cheerio.load(htmlData);

    var result = $('label.filterLabel');

    var reviewObj = [];

    for(var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {

        result[i].children.forEach((c) => { 
            if (c.children) c.children.forEach ( (gr) => { 
                if (gr.type === 'text')  { 
                    if (reviewObj[i] === undefined) reviewObj[i] = {};
                    if (gr.parent && gr.parent.attribs && gr.parent.attribs.class === 'row_label') { 
                        reviewObj[i].name = gr.data;
                    } else {
                        reviewObj[i].value = gr.data;
                    }
                }
            })
        });
    }

    return reviewObj;
}

var options = {
    url: restaurantUrl,
    method: "get"
};

console.log('Requesting page..');

request(options, function (error, response, body) {

    if (error) {
        console.error('error:', error);
    } else {
        console.log('Response: StatusCode:', response && response.statusCode);
        let reviews = getReviewSummaries(body);
        console.log('Review summary: \r\n', reviews);
        let details = getReviewDetails(body);
        console.log("\r\n");
        console.log('Review details: \r\n', details);
    }
});
```

You'll see a result like this, review dates are shown now:

```
Response: StatusCode: 200
Review summary:
 [ { name: 'Excellent', value: '554' },
  { name: 'Very good', value: '92' },
  { name: 'Average', value: '32' },
  { name: 'Poor', value: '9' },
  { name: 'Terrible', value: '6' } ]


Review details:
 [ { date: '24 June 2018',
    title: 'Whatever you choose, you can\'t go wrong' },
  { date: '23 June 2018', title: 'That\'s Amore!' },
  { date: '20 June 2018', title: 'Amazing pasta' },
  { date: '20 June 2018', title: 'Best Pizza' },
  { date: '18 June 2018', title: 'Italian food' },
  { date: '16 June 2018', title: 'Boston Dinner Adventure' },
  { date: '11 June 2018',
    title: 'Delicious food - friendly service' },
  { date: '3 June 2018',
    title: 'Hearty, Homemade, and Delicious!!!' },
  { date: '31 May 2018',
    title: 'Amazing dinner - YOU WON\'T LEAVE HUNGRY!!!' },
  { date: '31 May 2018', title: 'Homemade ' } ]
```

Comment: quite nice and useful, only thing would be how to get not just the aggregated reviews, but reviews and time of review (2 days ago, 1 week ago, ...) relations. Also, what is `label.filterLabel`?

Comment: Agreed! If the detailed data is available we can scrape it out. The label.filterLabel selector is just looking for matching Html elements  ( that contain the review data )

Comment: I'll update the answer pulling more details if I can. This should be possible!

Comment: This now includes dates and review summary!